# Problem getting results from mysql database via php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dynamic

I try to realize the following:

I generate via php a table of two fields (about training lessons) - lessons' name and location.
This table has several rows and i implemented an  like this:

```
        <table border='0' id='testing'>
            <thead>
                <tr class='small_title_bold'>
                    <th>Formation</th><th align='center'>Niveau</th><th align='center'>Ville</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>        
              <?php
              db_connect();

              if (isset($etablissement)){
                $sql_find_id_etablissement = "select id_etablissement, subdesignation, address1, address2, zip, city, town, department, phone, fax, www from etablissements where designation = '$etablissement' and id_region='$id_region'";
                $result_find_id_etablissement = mysql_query($sql_find_id_etablissement, $connection) or die('error');
                while ($row_find_id_etablissement = mysql_fetch_row($result_find_id_etablissement)){
                $id_etablissement  = $row_find_id_etablissement[0];
                $subdesignation = $row_find_id_etablissement[1];            
                $address1 = $row_find_id_etablissement[2];
                $address2 = $row_find_id_etablissement[3];          
                $zip = $row_find_id_etablissement[4];
                $city = $row_find_id_etablissement[5];
                $town = $row_find_id_etablissement[6];          
                $department = $row_find_id_etablissement[7];            
                $phone = $row_find_id_etablissement[8];
                $fax = $row_find_id_etablissement[9];
                $www = $row_find_id_etablissement[10];

                print "<tr class='small_subtitle_bold'><td colspan='3' align='center'>".$id_etablissement."-". $subdesignation."</td></tr>";        
                $sql_find_master = "select id_master, designation, master_level from masters where id_etablissement = '$id_etablissement' order by designation, master_level";
                $result_find_master = mysql_query($sql_find_master, $connection) or die('error');

                $count=mysql_num_rows($result_find_master);

                for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {                
                    $row_find_master = mysql_fetch_row($result_find_master);
                    $id_master = $row_find_master[0];   
                    $designation = $row_find_master[1]; 
                    $level = $row_find_master[2];
                    if($i % 2) {
                        print "<tr class='univ' bgcolor='#A4D2FD'>";
                        print "<td><a class='univ' href='master-details.php?master-id=".$id_master."&etablissement-id=".$id_etablissement."' onclick='popup('master-details.php?master=".$designation."')>".$designation."</a></td><td class='small_text' align='center'>".$level."</td><td class='small_text' align='center'>".$town."</td>";
                        print "</tr>";
                    }
                    else {
                        print "<tr class='univ' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
                        print "<td><a class='univ' href='#' onClick='javascript:swapContent(".$id_master.",".$id_etablissement.")'>".$designation."</a></td><td class='small_text' align='center'>".$level."</td><td class='small_text' align='center'>".$town."</td>";
                        print "</tr>";          
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When a user clicks a row, i want to run a mysql query and present the results (the lesson's details) in a separated  located in the same page without reloading the page.

I placed the following script in my head section:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function swapContent(id_master, id_etablissement) {
var url = "master-details.php";
$.post(url, {id_master: id_master, id_etablissement: id_etablissement} ,function(data) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content', function () {alert('Query was performed.');} );
      $( "#queryResults" ).empty().append( content );
});
}
</script>
```

I want my jquery script to run a php file named master-details with the parameters id_master and id_etablissement and returns the results in a DIV section named queryResults.

However, when I clicked on a row in my table, nothing happened.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to correct SQL injection, which is **a grave security risk**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
jQuery("tr").live("click", function(){
   $.post///what you already have.
});
```

You just need a way to tell it to do something when you click.

Comment: Alternatively, s/he might want to use `jQuery('tr').click(callback)` shorthand method.

Comment: Dear Senica,Thanks for your prompt reply. I placed this instruction as you suggested, however nothing changed.

Comment: Could my problem reside in the way i call the javascript function in my php and pass variables ?

Comment: ok now, i made some changes in my javascript and I had the confirmation that i pass the correct url to the function. However, nothing is returned and displayed in my DIV queryResults.

Answer (score 0):

> ...when I clicked on a row in my table, nothing happened.

Something happened, even if it was not apparent. The task is to determine exactly what happened, and why it didn't produce the expected results.

There are several steps you can take to determine what really happened:

1. Check for Javascript errors. You can use Firebug for Firefox or the built in Developer Tools for Chrome to view the Javascript console. If a Javascript error occurred, it will be shown there.
2. Determine if the PHP script was executed. You can do this by checking your webserver's logs, or by looking at the "Network" tab of the aforementioned tools.
3. If the PHP script is successfully executing, determine what output it produces. You can do this by running the script directly. Find the URL that your AJAX call references, and paste it into your browser's address bar. Is the output what you expect it to be?
4. If the PHP script executes and returns appropriate results, check your Javascript selectors. Are you sure they reference the correct div? Does that div exist?

Comment: Dear George,
thanks. I like this methodology. I implemented firebug but the console is quite complicate to me as i never used it.
However, when i clicked on one row of my table, i did not see any reference to the "master-details.php" my script is supposed to call.

Comment: @didier: When you click the "Console" tab in Firebug and then click your table row, does any red (error) text appear in Firebug?

Comment: No nothing red... when i clicked on a row, i see a reference to the php file my script calls ("master-details.php") and look to the tab POST, i can see that the two variables i passed to master-details.php are correct.

Comment: Next step, then. Does the PHP script get executed? What do your server logs tell you?

Comment: First, thank you for your patience. When i click on a row, firefox console does not log any event.

Comment: First, thank you for your patience. Looking to firebug console, when i click a row, i got: POST http://localhost/etudes_france/gr/master-details.php 200 OK 599ms. However, looking to firefox console, i can't see any event. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, this helps. The next step is to find out what the script returns. The POST tab may show it as output, or you can past the URL in your browser's address bar to see the results more clearly.

Comment: i don't see exactly what you mean. The returned url is correct, except that i do not have the two variables. Rather than having: http.../master-details.php, i should have: http.../master-details.php?id_master=26&id_etablissement=281

Comment: ok now, i made some changes in my javascript and I had the confirmation that i pass the correct url to the function. However, nothing is returned and displayed in my DIV queryResults.